# Hibernate mapping non-entity class with List

Tags: java, hibernate

I have 3 classes - Patient, AllergyList and Allergy.  Both Patient and Allergy are @Entity and AllergyList simply has a variable with a list of Allergiest.

```
@Entity
public class Allergy {
    private String id;
    private String name;

    public Allergy(String i, String n) {
        id=i;
        name=n;
    }

    @Id
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String n) {
        this.name = n;
    }
}
```

The Allergy class MUST have an id, and is referenced by other class in my program.

```
public class AllergyList {
    private List<Allergy> allergies = new ArrayList<Allergy>();

    public List<Allergy> getAllergies() {
        return allergies;
    }

    public void setAllergies(List<Allergy> a) {
        this.allergies = a;
    }
}
```

I need to have this class, because I have inherited the program, and cannot change the existing codebase.

```
@Entity
public class Patient {
    private String id;
    private AllergyList allergyList = new AllergyList();
    public Patient() {}

    @Id
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public AllergyList getAllergyList() {
        return allergyList;
    }

    public void setAllergyList(AllergyList allergyList) {
        this.allergyList = allergyList;
    }
}
```

And the main...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Patient patient = new Patient();
    patient.setId("100001");

    List<Allergy> allergies = new ArrayList<Allergy>();
    allergies.add(new Allergy("1","Dust"));
    allergies.add(new Allergy("3","Apple"));
    allergies.add(new Allergy("4","Bee"));

    patient.allergyList.setAllergies(allergies);

    .
    .
    session.save(patient);
    .
    .
}
```

So the above three classes are what I'm given.  I need to create allergy_list table that contains the following:

```
allergy_list
    patient_id
    allergy_id
```

I know I can create a List inside the Patient class, but the way the program is written I need to access the Allergy through the AllergyList class.  How can I annotate to make this happen?  Is it even possible?